# Array<Union of type>to Array<Union of generic type>

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, union-types, generic-type-argument

I'm trying to define the relationship between two array type, related by a Wrapper generic type:

```js
interface WrapperType<T> {
  innerValue: T;
}

type InnerArrayType = (TypeA | TypeB | TypeC)[];
type WrappedArrayType = (WrapperType<TypeA>|WrapperType<TypeB>|WrapperType<TypeC>)[];
```

However, the information between the two union types. When one of them changes, the other one must be manually changed as well. I wonder if there is a reusable utility type that can take the InnerArrayType and the WrapperType and output WrappedArrayType.

```
type MagicUtility<T> = ???????

type WrappedArrayType = MagicUtility<InnerArrayType>;
// equivalent to
type WrappedArrayType = (WrapperType<TypeA>|WrapperType<TypeB>|WrapperType<TypeC>)[];
```

In my use case, the list of TypeA, TypeB, TypeC... is predefined, static, and finite. Note that they are NOT string types.

**UPDATE**

I was able to get `Array<Generic of union>` with the method below. So there is a way to convert `Array<Generic of union>` to `Array<Union of generic>`, the problem would be solved. However, it seems to be an impossible problem: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27272.

```js
interface MyWrapper<T> {
    inner: T;
}

type ArrayOfUnionToArrayOfUnionOfGeneric<T> = 
  T extends (infer U)[]
  ? MyWrapper<U>[]
  : never;

type Inner = (1 | 2 | 3)[];
type Outer = ArrayOfUnionToArrayOfUnionOfGeneric<Inner> // MyWrapper<1 | 2 | 3>[]

// MyWrapper<1 | 2 | 3>[] --(HOW???)--> (MyWrapper<1>|MyWrapper<2>|MyWrapper<3>)[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types): the `U extends infer V` part is what distributes over the union.

```
type MagicUtility<T extends any[]> =
  (T extends (infer U)[] ? U extends infer V ? WrapperType<V> : never : never)[]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oG8AeAuKA7ArgLYBGEATgL4BQoks8AQiuiDgSedbdHJAMLM0ALzZFSlKlQCWuYOQBmAQwDG0AOplFYSGV4QAPDAB86KlCgzc5AGqKANvgg4YAbirUa8KAElcVsghkmiB6zAAUekgAPvSQTDF6fACUANoAum7cUBpakAAmgcGhqGE52uR6hvAIRlFlOpV6DLX1FfBV-EapGZJZALKKAOZSygCqwFJ2UqCGUBAYcrh5AM5Qirgg6SbIZlARcwsQS6thMvLkUKPdUAD8lweLKxa452RQ1rfZmuW67dYmbAgADcLoCQWRupIAPRQvatX6QDqIEwxeGNRgor65NqIxJddKeOgAJQgy3wdmAzAGwzGEymM18-kKihC8CMVCAA)